# pdflatex.EXE did not succeed

Tags: pdftex, miktex, miktex2.9

I have trouble with executing any file, where as the same file seems to work without any errors on my home PC. Both are MiKTeX 2.9 x64. I have updated all packages as well, is anyone else facing the same issues ? Any advise ?

***MWE:***

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{Introduction to \LaTeX{}}
\author{Author's Name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Here is the text of your introduction.

\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation}
    \alpha = \sqrt{ \beta }
\end{equation}

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Write your subsection text here.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{myfigure}
    \caption{Simulation Results}
    \label{simulationfigure}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusion}
Write your conclusion here.

\end{document}
```

***ERROR shown in pdflatex.log (under /appdata directory):***

```
======================================================================

Unfortunately, the package miktex-latex could not be installed.Please check the log file:
C:/Users/asukumari/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log
======================================================================

Sorry, but miktex-makefmt did not succeed for the following reason:

  The input file could not be found.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/asukumari/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/asukumari/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

2017-05-22 13:16:41,338-0400 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2017-05-22 13:16:41,338-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2017-05-22 13:16:41,338-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2017-05-22 13:16:41,338-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 691
```

Comment: It is not a problem of your document but of your installation. The formats seems not be there and perhaps other things too. Check if your system is up-to-date: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388